# Confusion with simple If-Else statement regarding duplicate values?

Tags: c#, winforms

Conundrum here which is taking up about half an hour (and counting) of my time.

Here, I have one common form for entering new and updating existing artwork details. I have three variables:

1. `bool isNew`: `true` when user selected 'New Artwork' to enter form,
   `false` when 'Update Artwork'.
2. `int artworkId`: The Artwork unique field to be entered
3. `int[] currentIds`: An `artworkId` array

My code for a Save function (nothing special yet):

```
if (isNew && currentIds.Contains(artworkId)) {
    MsgBox("Artwork exists");
} elseif ... {
    //Help here!!
    MsgBox("Artwork exists");
} else {
    //Everything is okay
    //Continue
}
```

How do I add the `elseif` condition (or better, attach it with `&&` to the first `if`) wherein user is updating (`isNew = false`) and is allowed to enter the same/current `artworkId` but not those existing in `currentIds`?  A typical scenario here would be when user chose to update artwork, form opens, fields other than `artworkId` are changed, then clicked Save.

Thanks!

Comment: If I understand correctly your problem, you want to avoid your user to change the artworkId to something already present in the array _excluding_ itself. Is this right?

Comment: @Steve Yes sir. :)

Comment: Then you need to save somewhere the initial value before the user starts the editing and then check the array if it contains the edited value excluding the initial value

Comment: By the way, it isn't a good idea to let your users change the value used to identifying your artwork details. Why do you allow them to change this value? This should hidden from them.

Comment: Shouldn't it just be `else` instead of `else if`? You want to make sure update is selected(`!isNew`) **AND** `artworkId` is not already in `currentIds` (`!(currentIds.Contains(artworkId))`). The opposite of both of these was checked in the earlier `if` so an `else` should do for updation. Am I missing something?

Comment: I thought of doing the saving thing, but I would have to create variables per unique fields required. Like, five unique fields equals five more variables... would this be okay in terms of optimization?

Comment: Can you provide more code? Showing what exactly `artworkId` stores. Some more context would be helpful.

Comment: @MasterYushi Hey thanks, but I'm afraid that's basically there is to the code. `artworkId` is just from a `TextBox` which the user types into. It's just one of those fields that have to be unique, kinda like "username" is to a "user account". :)

Comment: Make a global variable say 'currentID' and now add callbacks to when the textbox gains focus. Update the currentID inside the callback. Now compare the currentID in your else if part like this : `else if(!isNew && currentID != artworkId) MsgBox("You are NOT allowed to enter some other ID");`
I wrote this on what I understood till now. If this is not what you mean then can you explain on how as a user(not coder) I will go about using this particular part of app.